# PowerShell script to replace the tag value from one file to another file (tag value)

Tags: xml, powershell, automation

I need to replace the tag value into one file from another file by using powershell script.

Example:

File A:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
    <RunConfiguration>
        <EnvironmentVariables>          
      <BRANCH>MASTER</BRANCH>
    </EnvironmentVariables>
    </RunConfiguration>
</RunSettings>
```

Below value need to be replaced every time I execute the script:

```
<BRANCH>MASTER</BRANCH>
```

File B: (Here Branch name will update every time and I need to replace the dynamic values from this file into the File A's Branch tag)

**FileName**: branch.txt

**Value**: Branch-Name

PS: It should not append the file A, just replace the values

I've tried below powershell script but it's appending the value instead of replacing and also it works only with static values.

Here .runsettings is my File A name

```
$filePath = 'C:\BuildAgent\work\5eb597bdb0233b69\.runsettings'
$tempFilePath = "C:\BuildAgent\work\5eb597bdb0233b69\.runsettings"
$find = '<BRANCH>main</BRANCH>'
$replace = '<BRANCH>develop</BRANCH>'

(Get-Content -Path $filePath) -replace $find, $replace | Add-Content -Path $tempFilePath
```

$replace value will change every time, there will be a different branch name everytime, so my powershell script should be able to read the values inside from File B (Contains the branch name ex: develop or any other) and able to just replace the value in File A (.runsettings BRANCH tag) as mentioned above.

I don't know how to fetch the dynamic value from File B and replace it on runtime with File A's BRANCH value.

Comment: Show us an example of what FileB looks like

Comment: FileB is only having the branch name

File B:
cat branch.txt
develop

Comment: So if FileB contains `cat branch.txt develop`, you need to split the branch name from that using `((Get-Content -Path 'Path\to\FileB.txt' -Raw) -split '\s')[-1]` or `(Get-Content -Path 'Path\to\FileB.txt' -Raw) -replace '.*\s(\w+)$', '$1'`. Then use [iRon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68064436/9898643) to update FileA

Comment: Thanks @Theo for your response, just want to ask one more thing, how to replace the value from 'Path\to\FileB.txt' with FileA: .runsettings BRANCH value?

Comment: Capture the value you read from file B in a variable `$branch = ((Get-Content -Path 'Path\to\FileB.txt' -Raw).Trim() -split '\s')[-1]` and use that where iRon hardcoded `'Develop'`

Comment: Thanks @Theo and iRon, your provided solution is working perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it is a bad practice to peek and poke directly into a structured text files (like [`XML`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML)) using string methods as `Replace`. Instead it is recommended to use the related (`XML`) parser.
As an example:

```
$Xml = [Xml]'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
  <RunConfiguration>
    <EnvironmentVariables>
      <BRANCH>Master</BRANCH>
    </EnvironmentVariables>
  </RunConfiguration>
</RunSettings>'

$Xml.RunSettings.RunConfiguration.EnvironmentVariables.BRANCH = 'Develop'

$Xml.Save('C:\BuildAgent\work\5eb597bdb0233b69\test.xml')
```