# How to add and remove Lines Powershell Script

Tags: powershell

this is my script:

```
foreach ($Prog in $input) {
    (Get-Content $Prog.CamPath) | Foreach-Object {
            $_ # send the current line to output
                 if ($_ -match '!')  {  
                '<139 \Komponente\'
                'IN="4Seiten_fuegen.mpr"'
                'XA="0.0000"'
                'YA="0.0000"'
                'ZA="0.0000"'
                'EM="0"'
                'PR="0"'
                'VA="length 500.0000"'
                'VA="width 500.0000"'
                'VA="rotation 0.0000"'
                'KO="00"'
                '!'
        }
    } | Set-Content $Prog.CamPath
}
```

It adds those Lines beneth the "!"

The Result ist something like that:

```
!
<139 \Komponente\
IN="4Seiten_fuegen.mpr"
XA="0.0000"
YA="0.0000"
ZA="0.0000"
EM="0"
PR="0"
VA="length 500.0000"
VA="width 500.0000"
VA="rotation 0.0000"
KO="00"
!
```

It works all fine. I just need to remove the first "!"
Ive googled for hours! nothing works.

Could anybody just tell me how to modify my script?
Probably something like

```
-remove ("!","")
$_remove ('!','')
```

I dont know where and how....

kind regards

Comment: It looks like you trying to poke in a structured ([xml](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML)) string. This is a bad programming practice! Instead it is recommended to [use the related (XML) parser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68064436/1701026).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to only output `$_` *after* you've tested whether it contains `!`:

```
... |ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -match '!')  {  
        '<139 \Komponente\'
        'IN="4Seiten_fuegen.mpr"'
        'XA="0.0000"'
        'YA="0.0000"'
        'ZA="0.0000"'
        'EM="0"'
        'PR="0"'
        'VA="length 500.0000"'
        'VA="width 500.0000"'
        'VA="rotation 0.0000"'
        'KO="00"'
    }
    $_
}
```

Comment: this just adds another "!" at the end
the "!" before <139.... etc. is still there

Comment: @carpenter123 Did you try it? :) Your original example had a `'!'` line at the bottom of the `if` statement, I removed that - meaning you'll get the exact output you asked for.

Comment: yes right!  but i need to get rid of the  first "!" at the beginning of my result

Comment: @carpenter123 yes, that's solved by moving the `$_` line to the end of the loop body :)

Comment: ah okay, move....  ill check

Comment: That worked! What a .... i´ve tried like 7 hours ... Thank you so much! That was so cool! Ive added hundereds of versions with remove _remove -remove and hat not! Thank you so much!